# How to create a loop to return to the start of a function python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am unable to get my `while` loop to start back at the beginning not to sure what is wrong.

First attempt

```
def start() :

if choice in weapon:
    print('You have taken the ') + choice + (',this is now in your backpack.\n')  
    inventory.append(choice)

else:
    print("Uh oh, I don't know about that item")

start()
```

second attempt

```
the_choice = False
while not the_choice:
if choice in weapon:
    print('You have taken the ') + choice + (',this is now in your backpack.\n')  
    inventory.append(choice)
    the_choice = True
     # boom no loop needed 
else:
    print("Uh oh, I don't know about that item")
    the_choice = False
```

I just can't seem to figure it out, any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Is this code indented exactly like it is in the file on your computer?  Indentation is really important in python and could be the caus of your problem.

Comment: I am coding in visual studio the indentation looks to be correct however.

Comment: Visual studio isn't made for python generally... not that it can't just there are better editors out there

Comment: Sorry I take that back this now works thank you for you help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second attempt looks close, but you need an esape if all items are done: but look at your spaces: the if is inside the while: (this code is untested, just to show the reasoning...)

```
choice = next_choice() 
found = false
while not found:
    if choice in weapon_stash:
        inventory.append(choice)
        found = True
    else:
       choice = next_choice() # get from user?
       if choice == None:
           break; # break out on some condition otherwise infinite loop

# found is now either true (a thing was found), or false (the user quit)
```

Comment: `False` not `false`.  Also, this will never run, because `found` starts as false.  I think you're looking for `while not found:`

Comment: I have corrected the indentation err's thanks guys, although the code above give a false is not define error.

Comment: Sorry I take that back this now works, thank you for your help.

Comment: I .. uh... dont remember writing & and not not.. but i was typing on the fly rathe then tested code. I will update.

Answer (score 2):

The reason I commented Visual Studio might not be the best python editor is that other editors would have warned you that you did not increase the indentation after your function definition `start()` in your first attempt, nor did you indent after the start of your `while` loop in your second attempt. It always helps to include your error messages to help describe your problem, but if I were to guess, you are getting something to the tune of `IndentationError` messages.

Indentation is one of the most important concepts of python coding and serves the same purpose as curly braces in java or c++. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Indentation) has a pretty straightforward description of how to do it.

As for editors, I am a personal fan of [spyder](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder) although there are many great ones out there: [Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/), [pydev](http://www.pydev.org/), etc..

Answer (score 0):

There are only indentation faults in the second attempt.
Try below code.

```
the_choice = False
while not the_choice:
    if choice in weapon:
        print('You have taken the ') + choice + (',this is now in your backpack.\n')  
        inventory.append(choice)
        the_choice = True
        # boom no loop needed 
    else:
        print("Uh oh, I don't know about that item")
        the_choice = False
```

This will stuck in a constant loop if the user keeps entering a value not in the list (weapon), so you can put a counter for every `False` and update like below.

```
counter=0
the_choice = False
while not the_choice:
    if choice in weapon:
        print('You have taken the ') + choice + (',this is now in your backpack.\n')  
        inventory.append(choice)
        the_choice = True
        # boom no loop needed 
    else:
        print("Uh oh, I don't know about that item")
        the_choice = False
        counter=counter+1

    if counter >= 3:
        print('You have made 3 wrong attempts ')
        break
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work if I pick something within my list (weapon), however is I type something different in I have an constant loop.

Comment: you can use a break statement.. 
I will update my answer.